# Commento run with docker-compose if there is an existing Postgres instance running

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I can run `commento` with vanilla docker, but get a `[ERROR] database_connect.go:31 dbConnect(): cannot talk to postgres, retrying in 10 seconds (4 attempts left): pq: unknown authentication response: 10` when I try to run the `.yml` configuration file with docker-compose.

I suspect this is because I have a separate `Postgres` instance running on my server that is linked to my Django models. I'd like to keep the two instances separate if I can so Commento runs on it's own db instance.

How can I do this without shutting down my original Postgres?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is outdated dependency in Commento.

- [Ancient dependency versions in go.mod (#361) · Issues · Commento / Commento · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/commento/commento/-/issues/361)

If you could use Docker Compose to set up Commento, I think the easiest way is to downgrade PostgreSQL container version.

- [Using Docker · Commento](https://docs.commento.io/installation/self-hosting/on-your-server/docker.html)

I have tested `commento:v1.8.0` and `postgres:11.4` and it works fine. Just add version to these declaration in official yaml file.

- commento:v1.8.0 released on 2020-04-11 [Container Registry · Commento / Commento · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/commento/commento/container_registry/337942)
- postgres:11.4 released on 2019-07-18 [Image Layer Details - postgres:11.4 | Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/11.4/images/sha256-c472942d4b361e052c1a2892ee2a534951ebf7a0a68d205733f546a086d8bd63?context=explore)
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Docker 20.10.17

[docker-compose.yml · master · Commento / Commento · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/commento/commento/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/commento/commento:v1.8.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      COMMENTO_ORIGIN: http://commento.example.com:8080
      COMMENTO_PORT: 8080
      COMMENTO_POSTGRES: postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/commento?sslmode=disable
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - db_network
  db:
    image: postgres:11.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: commento
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    networks:
      - db_network
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  db_network:

volumes:
  postgres_data_volume:
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this is working anymore... I'm surprised by the lack of maintainership Commento has. Almost like the team is de-incentivized to support self-hosting process so people will begrudgingly opt for the paid service.